# Counting different ranges over the same dataset efficiently/simply

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a function in Postgresql that will return some metrics, calculated for a specific timezone (input).

Sample result:

[image]

The major issue is that this is only one metric. I need to get other 9 metrics from other tables.

Any suggestions for a less verbose way of achieving this?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard_metrics(destination_timezone TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE(
  metric TEXT,
  count BIGINT
  ) AS
  $func$
  DECLARE
    today        TIMESTAMP;
    tomorrow     TIMESTAMP;
    yesterday    TIMESTAMP;
    ereyesterday TIMESTAMP;
    last7days    TIMESTAMP;
    last30days   TIMESTAMP;
    last60days   TIMESTAMP;
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone
    INTO today;
    SELECT ('tomorrow' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone)
    INTO tomorrow;
    SELECT ('yesterday' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone)
    INTO yesterday;
    SELECT ('yesterday' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) - INTERVAL '1 day'
    INTO ereyesterday;
    SELECT ('today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) - INTERVAL '7 days'
    INTO last7days;
    SELECT ('today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) - INTERVAL '30 days'
    INTO last30days;
    SELECT ('today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) - INTERVAL '60 days'
    INTO last60days;
    RETURN QUERY
--TODAY
    (SELECT
       'ideastoday' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= today AND created_on < tomorrow AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
(SELECT
       'ideasyesterday' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= yesterday AND created_on < today AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT
       'ideasereyesterday' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= ereyesterday AND created_on < yesterday AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT
       'ideaslast7days' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= last7days AND created_on < today AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT
       'ideaslast30days' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= last30days AND created_on < today AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT
       'ideaslast60days' :: TEXT AS metric,
       COUNT(1)             AS count
     FROM analytics_ideas
     WHERE created_on >= last60days AND created_on < today AND analytics_ideas.space_id = 1);
  END
  $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of the other metrics you mentioned might complicate things, but the function you've given can be simplified quite a bit.

At a high level, this is what it usually comes down to: if you want your metrics to share **logic**, you need to differentiate them with **data**. You need a common data structure to encapsulate everything which distinguishes one metric from another. With that, you can write a generalised algorithm to process these structures.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard_metrics(destination_timezone TEXT)
  RETURNS TABLE(
    Metric TEXT,
    Count BIGINT
  ) AS
$func$
  WITH MetricDef (Metric, StartDay, EndDay) AS (
    VALUES
      ('ideastoday',         0,  1),
      ('ideasyesterday',    -1,  0),
      ('ideasereyesterday', -2, -1),
      ('ideaslast7days',    -7,  0),
      ('ideaslast30days',  -30,  0),
      ('ideaslast60days',  -60,  0)
  )
  SELECT
    MetricDef.Metric,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM
    MetricDef,
    analytics_ideas
  WHERE
    created_on >= ('today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) + MetricDef.StartDay * INTERVAL '1 day' AND
    created_on < ('today' AT TIME ZONE destination_timezone) + MetricDef.EndDay * INTERVAL '1 day' AND
    analytics_ideas.space_id = 1
  GROUP BY
    MetricDef.Metric
$func$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Note that this will not impose any kind of ordering on the output. If this is important, you should include a `DisplayOrder` field in the `MetricDef`, and add an `ORDER BY` somewhere in the main query.